# [Cocos2dx - TiledMap]Get black vertical lines when move map

Tags: cocos2d-x

I make a game with cocos2d-x and tilemap follow tutorial [Cocos2D-X Tile Map Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/39113/cocos2d-x-tile-map-tutorial-part-1)

It working fine but when i move map, i get black vertical lines on screen. 
http://i689.photobucket.com/albums/vv255/thansaulove/error2.png

Anyone have solution to fix it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: yup, make sure map/layer positions (and their parent's) is on exact pixel boundaries, ie 10,22 on non-retina, 20.5,44. on retina devices, never positions like 10.473548,22.5473. To do so cast position to int. But first multiply by content scale, cast to int, divide by 2.0 so that retina device can scroll to half points.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a way to fix this. It worked for me.

Find the ccCongig.h file and change the value of CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL to 1

Comment: Wow! it working fine. You save my time. thanks you so much :).I can't vote you now because Vote Up requires 15 reputation. I will vote you later :)

Comment: This is **not** a good fix, not even an acceptable workaround. As soon as you start moving the map you'll notice terrible aliasing effects because the tiles are slightly fluctuating in size while moving.